# Reconnecting interface from nmcli

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

I'm writing application in which I have to disable all network interfaces. Because `nmcli nm enable false` is only temporary (and autoconnects after some time), I use `nmcli dev disconnect iface [ifaceName]` but I don't know how to reconnect disconnected in this way device (from terminal or using some libs). I know that I can enable connections by `nmcli con up uuid [uuidNumber]`, but it requires knowledge about names of connections which were previously active. What is the better solution?

Comment: Can't you just stop networking altogether?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to have no IP address in any interface and I want to restore previous state after some actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get id like this:

```
 nmcli con show  | grep develop
 develop-vlan              179375b8-2bbf-4eeb-a50a-6710f22cb441   vlan
```

and connect like this:

```
 nmcli con up id develop-vlan
```